# not able to open the json file using python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

```
 {
    "appKey": "c6e2917da6dcc5e5dc5a57849eba1637ec92f98383c926aed8562154d63eb7fcd51bb57bd1907235ac2a553ab65fa3a29af2a7772829b890d6bc8e1f5a313bf1",
    "appId": "AUDI_SDS_2017_EXT_20151203",
    "cmdName": "DRAGON_NLU_ASR_CMD",
    "appName": "Python",
    "appVersion": "1",
    "language": "deu-DEU",
    "carrier": "carrier",
    "deviceModel": "deviceModel",
    "cmdDict": {
        "dictation_type": "ccpoi_dragondrive_specialized",
        "dictation_language": "deu-DEU",
        "locale": "germany",
        "application": "AUDI_2017",
        "organization_id": "Audi",
        "phone_OS": "4.0",
        "phone_network": "wifi",
        "audio_source": "SpeakerAndMicrophone",
        "location": "<48.396231, 9.972909> +/- 10.00m",
        "application_session_id": "1234567890",
        "utterance_number": "5",
        "ui_langugage": "de",
        "phone_submodel": "nmPhone2,1",
        "application_state_id": "45"
    }
}
```

The above is my json file and saved it as ENG_RequestData.json. I have similar json file as above and saved it as DEU_RequestData.json.

```
import json
import os
scriptPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ENG_RequestDataFile = scriptPath + "\ENG_RequestData.json"
print ENG_RequestDataFile
DEU_RequestDataFile = scriptPath + "\DEU_RequestData.json"

try:
    with open(ENG_RequestDataFile) as json_file:   
        #print json_file
        JSON_ENGData = json.load(json_file)
        print JSON_ENGData

    with open(DEU_RequestDataFile) as json_file:    
        JSON_DEUData = json.load(json_file)

except:
    print "[ERROR] FILE Cannot be opened"
```

The above code is trying to open the json file but I am getting the output as [ERROR] FILE Cannot be opened. I have specified the script path and also my .json files are there only. When I print the json path file it is printing exactly. can someone tell me what is the mistake ?

Comment: What exception is being generated?  A bare `except` is not helpful.

Comment: Probably better to use `os.path.join` on your filepaths

Comment: no its not working!! I tried it.

Comment: start by removing a line that might cause the issue, like the `location` line. if it works, you'll know that you need to do escaping etc there.

Comment: Agree with @ericosg, see if it's json's fault first by replacing with `{}`.

Comment: it is printing the path correctly, if I give - print DEU_RequestDataFile and print ENG_RequestDataFile but there is some problem within try and except loop.

Comment: @simon - where should I replace {} ?

Comment: @sam Replace the entire json file with it.

Comment: The json is valid and loads ok. No exception trace - nothing to answer.

Comment: it is working now . thanks

Comment: @sam so what was the issue?

Comment: i added this line : scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)